# curl -k in Okhttp3 / retrofit

Tags: curl, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to be able to use the equivalent of cURL's insecure mode (`-k`). essentially with cURL I can do something like `curl -XPOST -k http://my.link:port/path/to/endpoint`

Now I need to do the same in my java application. I use retrofit and okhttp3.

Currently my interface looks like:

```
public interface MyEndpoint {
  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
  @POST("/path/to/endpoint")
  Call<MyValue> getData(
        @Body RequestBody requestBody,
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create you OkHttp client with the following code which creates an insecure trust manager, ssl socket factory, and host name verifier.  Code is cut from the [OkCurl](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okcurl) implementation.  Remeber doing this negates the security provided by https.

```java
  private static X509TrustManager createInsecureTrustManager() {
    return new X509TrustManager() {
      @Override public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
      }

      @Override public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
      }

      @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
      }
    };
  }

  private static SSLSocketFactory createInsecureSslSocketFactory(TrustManager trustManager) {
    try {
      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {trustManager}, null);
      return context.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  private static HostnameVerifier createInsecureHostnameVerifier() {
    return new HostnameVerifier() {
      @Override public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
        return true;
      }
    };
}
```

Create your client with --

```java
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
X509TrustManager trustManager = createInsecureTrustManager();
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = createInsecureSslSocketFactory(trustManager);
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
builder.hostnameVerifier(createInsecureHostnameVerifier())
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```